# What significance does a odd or even function carry?

Tags: graphing-functions

In case if we happen to know some function is odd or even, what all information will that give us?

How much information can we extract from knowing whether it is odd or even?

How does this symmetry help?

Comment: One example that comes to mind is when you are integrating an odd function over a symmetric interval you get 0, which trivializes some pretty complicated integrals. Or for a Fourier series of an even or odd function, half of the terms vanish. There are many examples from all sorts of disciplines. In general, symmetry is a very useful property in problem-solving and modeling situations

Comment: Thanks a lot. @Alborz